# Missing parentheses in $s(k (s I I))(s(\lambda y. s(k y))(\lambda y. s I I)$ leads to interesting error in an nLab page. Need a double check.

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus, fixed-points, combinatory-logic, rewriting-systems

I think I found an error in the nLab [page on partial combinatory algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial+combinatory+algebra#FinallyClassicalConstruction) in the **Example combinators** section:

> Finally, consider the classical construction of the fixed-point combinator, $Y = \lambda y. (\lambda x. y(x x))(\lambda x. y(x x))$. We have firstly
> $$\lambda x. y(x x) = s(\lambda x. y)(\lambda x. x x) = s(k y)(s I I)$$
> which means
> $$\array{
> Y & = & \lambda y. (s I I)(s(k y)(s I I)) & (1)\\
>  & = & s(\lambda y. s I I)(\lambda y. s(k y)(s I I)) & (2)\\ 
>  & = & s(k (s I I))(s(\lambda y. s(k y))(\lambda y. s I I) & (3) \\ 
>  & = & s(k (s I I))(s(s (k s)(\lambda y. k y)))(k (s I I)) & (4) \\ 
>  & = & s(k (s I I))(s(s (k s)(s(k k)I)))(k (s I I)) & (5)
> }$$

I think I found an error.

$(3)$ has a missing closing parenthesis, i.e. $\big)$. The closing parenthesis can go in one of two positions. The error stems from there.

$(2)$ is equivalent to $(3)$ with a trailing closing parenthesis (emphasized):

$$s(k (s I I))(s(\lambda y. s(k y))(\lambda y. s I I)\Big)\qquad(3a)$$

On the other hand, $(4)$ is equivalent to $(3)$ with a closing parenthesis in the other possible position (emphasized):

$$s(k (s I I))(s(\lambda y. s(k y))\Big)(\lambda y. s I I)\qquad (3b)$$

---

Can someone with patience confirm? I’d use the [SKI combinator interpreter](http://ski.aditsu.net/) to double check, but it supports purely SKI input only (can’t mix in $\lambda$, variables, nor terms).

Comment: Are you sure the (1) step is correct? I see above your quoted section we have $λx.xx=s(λx.x)(λx.x)=sII$, but Y has no $λx.xx$ part...

Comment: Yes, it’s surprising, but yes. @Taroccoesbrocco’s answer addresses this!

Comment: Nice follow-up work over the weekend! Maybe (dependent) type theory is your next topic? :)

Comment: @mohottnad Thanks! Yes, I want to read "Types and Programming Languages" (TAPL) by Pierce. The first pages of TAPL outlined some prereqs that I need and suggested "Essentials of Programming Languages" (EOPL) by Friedman/Wand/Haynes as a way to get those prereqs (with "Programming Language Pragmatics" (PLP) by Scott as an alternative way to get the prereqs). I read that PLP is more of a reference book, so I decided on EOPL. EOPL tells me I need to know Scheme, but recommends "The Little Schemer" by Friedman, so I started reading "The Little Schemer" over the weekend.

Comment: My current plan is "The Little Schemer", then EOPL, then TAPL. Let me know if you have any advice and thanks for all the help (answering so many questions and clarifications!) and encouragement!

Comment: I haven't read any of the above CS oriented type theory books though I have some programming experience. Hope to continue to be able to help you and good learning!

Comment: @mohottnad thanks! Have learned much from your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree that what you have noticed is the only error among the equivalences, well spotted!

A missing parenthesis leads to the completely wrong conclusion that $S(K(SII))(S(S(KS)(S(KK)I)))(K(SII))$ is a fixed point combinator!
A proof that $S(K(SII))(S(S(KS)(S(KK)I)))(K(SII))$ is not a fixed point combinator is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4330824/288417).

---

To @mohottnad: Equivalence $(1)$ is$-$quite surprisingly$-$correct! Indeed,

$$Y = \lambda y. (\lambda x. y(xx)) (\lambda x. y(xx))$$
and we have that
\begin{align}
\lambda x. y(xx) &=_\beta S(Ky)(SII)
\\
\lambda x.xx &=_\beta SII
\end{align}
Since $(\lambda x.xx)(\lambda x.y(xx)) =_\beta (\lambda x.y(xx))(\lambda x.y(xx))$, we can conclude that
\begin{align}
Y &=_\beta \lambda y.(\lambda x.xx)(\lambda x.y(xx)) 
\\
&=_\beta \lambda y.(SII)(S(Ky)(SII))
\end{align}

I agree that the explanation on [nLab's page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial+combinatory+algebra#FinallyClassicalConstruction) could be a bit more lengthy and thorough. At first sight, I was convinced that equivalence $(1)$ was wrong, too.

---

An emended version of the equivalences in nLab's page about [partial combinatory algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial+combinatory+algebra#FinallyClassicalConstruction), Point 4 in section *Examples of Combinators*, would be the following:

\begin{align}
Y & =_\beta \lambda y. (S I I)(S(K y)(S I I)) 
\\
 & =_\beta S(\lambda y. S I I)(\lambda y. S(K y)(S I I)) 
\\ 
 & =_\beta S(K(S I I)) \big(S(\lambda y. S(K y))(\lambda y. S I I)\big)
 \\ 
&=_\beta S(K(SII)) \big(S(S(KS)K)(K(SII))\big) 
\end{align}

where, in the last equivalence, we used the fact that
\begin{align}
S(S(KS)K)(K(SII))
&\to_\beta^* S (\lambda y.(KSy)(Ky)) (K(SII))
\\
&\to_\beta^*  S (\lambda y. S(Ky)) (K(SII))
\\
&\to_\beta S(\lambda y. S(K y))(\lambda y. S I I)
\end{align}

Therefore, $S(K(SII)) \big(S(S(KS)K)(K(SII))\big) $ is a fixed point combinator, and this is consistent with Wikipedia's page about [fixed point combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Other_fixed-point_combinators).

Comment: Nice explanation and hard work! +1

Comment: Thanks! I’m now trying to fix the derivation by proceeding from $(3a)$ in OP. I’m stuck at converting $(\lambda y.s(ky))$ into an expression exclusively of $SKI$ terms. $\lambda y.s(ky) \rightarrow_{\beta} \lambda xyz.x(yz)$. Not sure how to proceed. Should I make this a separate question of its own?

Comment: @joseville - I edited my answer to show a correct derivation of the equivalences.

Comment: Thanks! I corrected the two “nLab” pages and linked to this answer in the revision notes.